# Single line ssh command that handles sub commands

Tags: ssh

I am looking to write a script that will send an ssh command over.  However, there will be sub commands after a command is entered. I was hoping to do this in a single line.

Example: ssh command

```
>showstuff
response:>what stuff would you like to show?(1,2,3,4):
>1
response:>would you like to show more info on that stuff?(y,n):
>y
response:>here you go
```

Is there something to do this in a single line? ie showstuff->1->y

Or is there another easy enough way to handle this?

Comment: Its not in a single line. The best I can think of is here scripts. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: You can do this sort of thing with [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), with which you could write a local script that could then be executed in a simple one line command over a single ssh call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great library for connecting with SSH.  Here's an example of what I used:

[Chilkat Example](https://www.example-code.com/csharp/ssh_multiple_commands.asp)

Link for the library is at the top of the example.  I used the ChannelSendString then the ChannelReceiveUntilMatch to wait for the response.  Then I sent another command via the ChannelSendString command.  Worked like a charm!

I've used this library for a bunch of solutions now.